# Refresh iframe when no user activity

Tags: html, iframe, android-activity, timeout, refresh

Updated Code

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8;" http-equiv="Content-Type;" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     //This goes into a script tag in your head tag
     var docTimeOut;

     function bodyTimeOut() {
         docTimeOut=setTimeout("updateFrame();",10000);
     }

     function resetTimeOut() {
         //alert('reset!');
         clearTimeout(docTimeOut);
         bodyTimeOut();
     }

     function updateFrame() {
         //Loads the page's html into the div
         //Uncomment this in your actual code
         $.get('https://www.creator.zoho.com/somePage/', function(data) {
             $('openPrintRun').html(data);
         });
         //alert('update!');
     }

     //This function runs when the DOM has finished loading
     $(function() {
         bodyTimeOut();
         //This binds the resettimeOut function the click, mousemove and mouseover events of the div
         $('#openPrintRun').bind('click mousemove mouseover', resetTimeOut);
     });
        // -->
    </script>


    <title>Untitled 1</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="openPrintRun" style="height:250px; width:100%;">
      </div>
     </body>

    </html>
```

I have an iframe that I want to refresh when there is no user activity. At the moment I am trying to use this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var docTimeOut;
function bodyTimeOut()
{
    docTimeOut=setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},1200);
}

function resetTimeOut()
{
    clearTimeout(docTimeOut);
    bodyTimeOut();
}


document.onload = bodyTimeOut;

document.getElementById('openPrintRun').onmouseover= resetTimeOut;
</script>
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe id="openPrintRun" height='250px' width='100%' name='zoho-Open_Print_Runs' frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' allowTransparency ='true' src='somepage.html'></iframe>  
</body>

</html>
```

But it does not seem to work. Is there a better or at least a correct way to do this?

Comment: After updating my code I am still having a trouble with it not reloading the iframe. Could the src link have anything to do with that at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're reloading the page you're on, not the iframe. There are a few ways to reload the iframe:

```
document.getElementById("openPrintRun").contentDocument.location.reload();
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("openPrintRun").contentWindow.location.reload();
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("openPrintRun").src = document.getElementById("openPrintRun").src;
```

**Edit**: This should replace the part in your script where you have: `location.reload();`

You can find a related question on another site [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=64667).

Also, make sure that the page you're loading isn't being cached or the page may appear to stay the same as it was when it was first loaded.

Comment: @shinjuo - Well, you have that already with your `onmouseover` of the iframe. You'll want to be careful though because if you switch it to only what Aaron said below and if they are typing (for example), it will still refresh and they will lose their info. Perhaps you could attach it to a few event handlers. ie. if they click, keypress, mouseover, mousemove, etc. it should reset the timer so it doesn't refresh while they're doing things in it. I'm not sure if you can use blur/focus events on an iframe but that's also worth looking into.

Comment: Sorry I was confused on where your lines of code went that you gave me but I see it now. Also if I want to add onkeypress and click, should I just add another line like:document.getElementById('openPrintRun').onkeypress= resetTimeOut; and just keep adding lines like that to get them all or is there a more efficient way to do it

Comment: @shinjuo: Sorry about that. I will edit my answer so that it's more clear. Yes, you can do it that way to add more events. One thing you could do is store the element in a variable and reuse that. Ex. `var ifrm = document.getElementById('openPrintRun');` and then use `ifrm.onclick = resetTimeOut; ifrm.onkeypress = resetTimeOut;` etc. (sorry can't post new lines here). Doing it this way won't make any noticeable difference but the idea is that it only has to do the getElementById lookup once.

Comment: One last thing you mentioned making sure the page isnt being cached. How would I do that?

Comment: @shinjuo: There are a couple of ways. If you're using a language like PHP or ASP(.Net) each of them has ways of preventing it. You can also use some html META tags. Check out [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067) site for some ways to do it with Asp and HTML.

Comment: I updated my code to the one above and it still doesnt seem like it is working. Is there anything I have done wrong. I have tried all three of your options you gave me

Comment: @shinjuo: Does it throw any errors? Try putting the script tag at the end of your body tag.

Comment: No errors it just doesnt refresh. I will put the script at the end and see what happens

Comment: @shinjuo: If I take your Updated code from above, and move the `<script>` tag immediately between `</iframe>` and `</body>`, it works (in Opera). You need to do this because when the browser is parsing your javascript, (ie. `var ifrm = document.getElementById('openPrintRun');`) that element doesn't exist yet if the script is in the `<head>` since the DOM hasn't finished loading. Now, I did some testing in other browsers and I noticed a few things. First off, use `window.onload` instead of `document.onload`. This worked in ie8, FF, Opera and Safari for me. ...

Comment: Secondly, the other browsers don't seem to fire those events for an iframe. I tried wrapping the iframe in a div and attaching the events that way, but that didn't work. Perhaps rather than using an iframe you could use ajax? I highly recommend taking a look at jQuery if you don't mind the extra footprint of the jquery file, it makes stuff like this quick even using ajax.

Comment: What would I use from jQuery instead of the iframe? I have used very little of jQuery

Comment: @shinjuo: Here, I've made a jQuery version for you that should work. I can't do a cross site request from there so I commented out the part where it gets the other file, but you should get the idea from here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NvrMT/3/)

Comment: The div doesnt seem to load the page I put in. I tested the one on the link you gave me and it doesnt seem to load anything eiter. Is there something I am doing wrong? Sorry for all the questions I really appreciate your help

Comment: @shinjuo: As I said, I commented out the part where it loads the page into the div. You should copy the html into the body of your test page, put the javascript into a script tag in the head, and then uncomment the `$.get(...);` line. Also, if you change the timeout to `1000` instead of `10000` it will be faster for testing purposes.

Comment: I did uncomment it but let me test it in a couple of different browsers to see what happens

Comment: @shinjuo: You might have to test it on a web server. I get this error when I run it locally in Opera: "XMLHttpRequest to files is disabled for security reasons. Set "Allow File XMLHttpRequest" with opera:config#UserPrefs|AllowFileXMLHttpRequest to disable this security check." Which is just saying it doesn't let you use local files for xmlhttprequests for security reasons.

Comment: I updated my code with what I have at the top and I have been testing it on my web hosting server. I changed the link i am using for security reason but I left semi what it looks like

Comment: @shinjuo: You forgot to include jquery. Add this line in the head above the other script tag: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: still nothing, could it be the link that I am trying to put in the div? Will that make any difference?

Comment: @shinjuo: You need to use a css selector as well (missed this last time) here: `$('openPrintRun')` should be `$('#openPrintRun')`. Try using relative paths too. Also, I think if you switch between a) subdomains or b) protocols (ie. http to https) it is considered a cross-site script and xhr will block it. See if you're getting any error messages.

Comment: Depending on your browser, find the "Error Log" (or similar) entry in the menu.

Comment: Here is the link to the site I have it testing on. www.digitalsoftwaresolutions.net/test/openPrintRuns.html

Comment: It's definitely a cross-site scripting issue. It's because you're trying to link to a different site with ajax. Sooo, you're going to have to go back to the iframe idea but I don't know how to attach those handlers if the browsers don't support it. You can try it with jquery (just add the iframe back in in place of the div).

Comment: Okay I think I have found a rickety work around for now. I put the iframe inside the div tag and made the div tag a little bigger than the iframe. So when you cross the div tag you reset the timer and have so many minutes to either cross that div path again or the form will reset. Seems to work for now I REALLY appreciate all the time you put in to help me

Comment: @shinjuo: No problem. Just remember that it also resets while they cross INTO the div (towards the iframe), not just out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `mousemove` event (is there activity when the user forgets the mouse pointer in the browser and walks away?) and attach it to the `body` element instead. It's possible that the `iframe` doesn't send such events (security: so you can't watch the mouse pointer from outside the frame).

Comment: You're saying to do it like this:document.body.onmousemove= resetTimeOut;

Comment: I'm not 100% sure with the syntax but yes, like this. If it doesn't work, create a `DIV` with the `id="debug"`. That way you can show debug output on the page without blocking: `document.getElementById('debug').innerHtml='some text'`